# Framing around gypsum block walls

Tags: bathroom, framing, remodeling

I am doing my bathroom remodeling. I have to reframe my ceiling as old one is all crooked. The issue I am facing is part of my walls are [gypsum blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gypsum_block) (*not drywall*)

What would be the best anchors to use to attach tracks for the perimeter on such walls. Somehow plastic with screw seems bit unreliable (*I might be mistaken of cause*).

Now it is a wooden frame, which is nailed to the surrounding walls. (*I am not sure if I could attach pictures here*). Basically it covers the all the pipes above.  Drywall with some plaster was attached to the old wooden frame before.

Now wood is nailed to the surrounding walls for the whole perimeter and the joist are ran across (*wooden joists*). The whole assembly is wobbling, So as I said, I plan to attach metal trucks and studs.  I have to somehow attach tracks at the perimeter. Some walls are from cinder blocks and there is not an issue to make secure attachment.

Question is: What to use on a gypsum blocks.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: You certainly can attach pics, and in this case, it will be _extremely_ helpful! Simply [edit] your post, then drag your images into the post. The site will upload & host them for you. If you're limited on images, post them to a site like imgur.com and put the link in your question - someone will embed them for you.

Comment: Some pictures of how those wobbly joists are laid would be really helpful - just on a rough guess of what I think it looks like, you probably need to add [masonry joist hangers](https://www.bpcfixings.com/images/main-images/joist-hangers-timber-masonry-connectors.jpg) attached to the gypsum blocks, which the joists then sit in (rather than sitting on top of the wooden perimeter). Gypsum blocks aren't designed to be load bearing though so this really depends how it all actually is set out. Maybe hang the joists from the cinders instead for example.

Comment: I would love to add the pictures but to my embarrassment i can't figure out how to do it here.   I will not use wood at all.  There is nothing really load bearing it is just to cover pipes which are running at concrete ceiling.  old frame is attached to gypsum blocks on two sides and two sides have cinder blocks. It is basically decorative ceiling which as i said covers up major  pipes.  the only load it would is the drywall sheet As it used before. Gypsum block walls are running from the concrete floor up to the concrete ceiling.

Comment: Until you earn some reputation points you can only link to images hosted elsewhere. The editor should explain that. Again, all that information should be in your question post, not down here.

Comment: Welcome @Den, this is a great question and as your "reputation" score increases you'll be allowed to drag photos directly "into" your question and StackExchange will host them for you.  Keep contributing!